# Removing a CSS element using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this function in my js file which is fine...

```
$('.pets').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.box2').removeClass('box').addClass('box-hover');
});
$('.pets').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.box2').removeClass('box-hover').addClass('box');
});
```

But, I also have a p element with display: none before this event. Is there a way that I can remove 'display: none' within my mouseenter/mouseleave function?

Comment: Could you show your relevant ([mcve]) code, rather than explaining it to us? Though I'd suggest `$(this).prev('div').toggle()` would possibly suffice.

Comment: It's really worth your time to [read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value): *"Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. `$( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "" )` — removes that property from an element..."*

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this. I'll give it a go thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To remove a specific CSS:

```
$("div").css({ 'display' : '', 'opacity' : '' });
```

To remove the whole inline style:

```
$("div").removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: I have tried both of these and can't understand why it's not working for me. Any suggestions??

Comment: If your CSS are inside the class, this will not work. This is for inline CSS

Comment: You can use the !important' for example ** $("div").css('display':'none!important')**and neutralize the class effect

Comment: I have tried to do it with inline styling also but still so cigar im afraid! Thanks a lot for your help, it's nice of you to share your knowledge. I have a fiddle with the problem if you would like to take a look https://jsfiddle.net/9eq38tu6/3/

Comment: I just created box-hover in my css and used it to replace class with box2..
I've now changed that whole deal by just using :hover like a normal person. Im sure ive confused you a lot by this point so I will just try to figure it out myself haha!

Answer (score 0):

Check This demo code it works

show p tag element when mouseenter - Make an id on `<p id="hide-elm">` tag

```
<div class="pets" style="width:200px;height:250px; background:#a4a4a4;"></div>
<br><br>
<div class="box2" style="width:200px;height:250px; background:#dedede;"></div>

<style>
.box-hover{
    background: red !important;

}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.pets').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.box2').removeClass('box').addClass('box-hover');
        $('#showme').show();
    });
    $('.pets').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.box2').removeClass('box-hover').addClass('box');
        $('#showme').hide();
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9eq38tu6/3/

Thanks for the input but my problem is a little different.. Here my code I would be greatful if you could help